# My for loop repeats multiple times the value

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

My for loop give the rights value but the problem is that It keep repeating itself. Ayways the code have to write in a file a given year and my age if my age is for example 17, while the year now is (2024). In my code when runned in this example I choose 2026
the code will write in the file:
Age 18 year 2025
Age 19 year 2026
I will do the same but backwards but I had issues with this for loop repeating

```
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now()
current_year = current_time.year

year = int(input('Until which year? '))
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
file_handle = open('Exam_file_handling', 'w')
difference = abs(year - current_year)
time_remaining = year - difference
future_age = age + difference

#for i in range(current_year, time_remaining, -1):
   # for j in range(age, time_remaining, -1):
      #  print(i, j)

for i in range(current_year + 1, year + 1, 1):
    for j in range(age, future_age, 1):
       print(i, j)
```

Do not use too complicated stuff, because I am a beginner.
only:
def,list,loops (while, for). That's about it. But If u can't find any other ways just help me with more complicated stuff.

I tried different combination of for loops, but it looks like it doesn't work I even tried to use while loop.

Comment: With two `for` loops, you are printing out every possible age, for every possible year.  You want *just one loop* - the year, perhaps - and then print that year and the calculated age for that year.

Comment: Hi! I want the if the year is 2024 i want to write to the chosen year which for example is 2026 and it will write what age I will be in 2025 and 2026 and the year but the issue is that whenever the code run it does the task but it will be like:
"" 2025
"" 2025
"" 2025
"" 2026
"" 2026
"" 2026

Answer (score 0):

if you compute the year of the birth, it is then straightforward to get the age for every possible year. Here is a small change to your code:

```
from datetime import datetime

#you can use one line to get te current year
current_year = datetime.now().year

year = int(input('Until which year? '))
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
file_handle = open('Exam_file_handling', 'w')

#given actual year and age, you can guess the year of the birth
birth_year = current_year - age

#between next year and final year, each year - birth_year will give you the age
for y in range(current_year +1, year+1):
     print(y-birth_year,y)
```

Comment: Hi i finished the code a long time ago. But either way I just wanted to know how to make remove the post 